# Is enough-url function deleted in hunchentoot-1.2.3?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

If so, how can i change the following code:

```
(script-path (tbnl::enough-url (ppcre:regex-replace-all "\\\\" script-name "/") uri-prefix))
```

thanks!

Comment: What is the function doinf? You'll have to explain that before anyone will have much of a chance to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this?

```
CL-USER> (puri:render-uri
          (puri:enough-uri "http://foo.bar.com/baz/blub"
                           "http://foo.bar.com/")
          nil)
"/baz/blub"
```